# Android SQlite update query

Tags: android, sqlite

i have an update query where i need to pass multiple parameter. Please guide how to do. Here in place of "id" i want multiple parameters for example name age.

//Code

```
   ContentValues updateCountry = new ContentValues();
   updateCountry.put("country_name", "United States");
   db.update("tbl_countries", updateCountry, "id=?", new String[] {Long.toString(countryId)})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
   ContentValues updateCountry = new ContentValues();
   updateCountry.put("country_name", "United States");
   db.update("tbl_countries", updateCountry, "id=? AND name=? AND age=?", new String[]{Long.toString(countryId),"name_value","age_value"});
```